# Case Statement with different data type

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am trying to return SLA days for particular conditions. However for a specific condition I want it to return a different data type. Current code is as follows:

```
      SELECT CASE
               WHEN fourthlevel.case_type IN
                       ('Complaint')
               THEN
                  (SELECT COUNT (*)
                     FROM work_days1
                    WHERE     work_days1.business_date >
                                 fourthlevel.cdate
                          AND work_days1.business_date <=
                                 COALESCE (fourthlevel.close_date,
                                           SYSDATE))
               WHEN fourthlevel.case_type IN ('Enquiry')
               THEN
                  (SELECT COUNT (*)
                     FROM work_days1
                    WHERE     work_days1.business_date >
                                 fourthlevel.create_date
                          AND work_days1.business_date <=
                                 COALESCE (fourthlevel.close_date,
                                           SYSDATE))
            END
               AS sla_days
       FROM fourthlevel
```

I want it to return for where case_status  = 'Cancelled' return 'N/A'. I know i cant do it like this but i will include the code so it is easier to understand:

```
    SELECT CASE
      WHEN fourthlevel.case_type IN ('Complaint')
      THEN
         (SELECT COUNT (*)
            FROM work_days1
           WHERE     work_days1.business_date > fourthlevel.cdate
                 AND work_days1.business_date <=
                        COALESCE (fourthlevel.close_date, SYSDATE))
      WHEN fourthlevel.case_type IN ('Enquiry')
      THEN
         (SELECT COUNT (*)
            FROM work_days1
           WHERE     work_days1.business_date > fourthlevel.create_date
                 AND work_days1.business_date <=
                        COALESCE (fourthlevel.close_date, SYSDATE))
      WHEN fourthlevel.case_status = 'Cancelled'
      THEN
         'N/A'
   END
      AS sla_days
    FROM fourthlevel
```

How do i do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `case` statement can only return one data type.  So convert the numbers to strings:

```
SELECT CASE
  WHEN fourthlevel.case_type IN ('Complaint')
  THEN
     (SELECT cast(COUNT(*) as varchar2(255))
        FROM work_days1
       WHERE     work_days1.business_date > fourthlevel.cdate
             AND work_days1.business_date <=
                    COALESCE (fourthlevel.close_date, SYSDATE))
  WHEN fourthlevel.case_type IN ('Enquiry')
  THEN
     (SELECT cast(COUNT(*) as varchar2(255))
        FROM work_days1
       WHERE     work_days1.business_date > fourthlevel.create_date
             AND work_days1.business_date <=
                    COALESCE (fourthlevel.close_date, SYSDATE))
  WHEN fourthlevel.case_status = 'Cancelled'
  THEN
     'N/A'
END AS sla_days
FROM fourthlevel
```

Alternatively, you could return `NULL` when the two conditions do not match.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! It is still not working for me however, while the code generates fine for both null and varchar solutions, the sla days remain the same as before. 

I am wondering if this is to to with the fact that the case statement looking at case_type (Complaint, Enquiry) are overwriting the cases that have case_status of Cancelled.

Is there a order in which the case statement executes? Or is it all simulataneous?

Comment: s there a order in which the case statement executes? YES from "top" to "bottom" so sequence it carefully, you also want to use ELSE

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. I reordered my case statement by putting the case_status condition at the very top. Man I would be lost without stackoverflow!