# SQL Server CASE expression not evaluating as expected

Tags: sql-server, casting, case

I suspect that I am not understanding how the CASE expression evaluates.

When I run this statement, I'm getting:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 7
>   The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

which, I understand; however, I'm not sure *why*. In the `CASE` expression, `WHEN 1` should be evaluated and no `CAST` should take place.

Am I misunderstanding how `CASE` works?

```
DECLARE @parameterID int = 42;
DECLARE @userID int = 3;
DECLARE @administratorID int = 2;

--parameterid of 42 has a parametertype of 1

With Param AS  
(
    SELECT 
        ParameterValue, USER_ID, P.PARAMETERTYPE_ID AS ParameterType 
    FROM 
        dbo.ParameterValues PV 
    INNER JOIN 
        Parameters P on P.ID = PV.PARAMETER_ID
    WHERE 
        PARAMETER_ID = @parameterID AND USER_ID = @userID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        ParameterValue, USER_ID, P.PARAMETERTYPE_ID AS ParameterType 
    FROM 
        dbo.ParameterValues PV 
    INNER JOIN 
        Parameters P on P.ID = PV.PARAMETER_ID
    WHERE 
        PARAMETER_ID = @parameterID AND USER_ID = @administratorID
)
SELECT TOP 1 
    TypedParmValue = 
    CASE P1.ParameterType
        WHEN 1 THEN P1.ParameterValue
        WHEN 2 THEN CAST(P1.ParameterValue AS datetime) 
        WHEN 3 THEN CAST(P1.ParameterValue AS DECIMAL(20,6))
        WHEN 4 THEN CAST(P1.ParameterValue as bit)
        ELSE P1.ParameterValue
    END,
    P1.ParameterType,
    P1.ParameterValue,
    PT.ParameterTypeName 
FROM 
    Param P1
INNER JOIN 
    ParameterTypes PT on P1.ParameterType = PT.ID
ORDER BY
    USER_ID DESC
```

Functionally, what I'm trying to do is look up a parameter (value is stored 'generically' as nvarchar) and then convert it to the proper datatype based on the type (as stored in parametertype).  The CTE is used to look for a user-specific parameter value or fallback to the default value.  I know that there are different/better ways of dealing with default parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you've misunderstood how `CASE` works.

First of all, it's an **expression** (like `a+b`) - not a statement.

Therefore, `CASE` has to return one atomic value (from several possibilities) - and all those return values have to be **of the same datatype**.

In your case - this is totally not the case; in such a situation, SQL Server will pick the datatype that's highest on the [data type precedence list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - which here is `DATETIME`.

So **all** values being returned will be attempted to be converted to `DATETIME` - and if `P1.ParameterValue` for `WHEN  1` isn't a valid `DATETIME`, this error occurs.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, what I'm trying to do, cannot be done in this manner.  Perhaps, instead of trying to do this in SQL, I should just pass the parametervalue and parametertype back to the manager and let the C# code perform the datatype conversion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770739/case-statement-with-different-data-type - this also provides a good explanation.

Comment: That's correct - the `CASE` expression can only ever return **one datatype** - depending on the possible values being returned, those need to be converted to whatever datatype the SQL Server runtime works out as the "return type" for that expression.